# Moving project from Eclipse into Intellij and now I am getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

So I just started learning spring-boot to make an API and for some reason, I am getting these specific errors whenever I try to run the program even though I did not have those issues in Eclipse.

**The Errors:**

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START

**Description:**

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

> org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)

The following method did not exist:

The method's class, javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/cj/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/cj/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.1/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/cj/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/cj/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration

Process finished with exit code 1

**My POM.xml file**

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Does it run when you do a `mvn spring-boot:run` ??

Comment: unfortunately it still does not work even after running that command

Comment: Include `spring-boot-starter-validation` and ditch the `validation-api` dependency. I also don't get why it should be loaded from `javaee-api-7.0.jar` as that isn't part of your dependencies. If it doesn't run with plain maven it won't run in your IDE.

Comment: Did you check if the intellij maven settings are point to the correct repository ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have changed it to starter validation just now. However I do not know how I'm supposed to change the load from javaee or remove it in intellij as that was the default and I don't remember configuring anything.

Comment: Remove it. It wasn't default you added it yourself somehow.

Comment: Yeah I just removed it and it seems to be working now. Thanks! still I don't remember adding that specific jar file